# Why should I use transaction over MSDTC instead of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction?

Tags: .net, transactions, msdtc

Assuming I am using only one sql server database

Why would one choose transaction over MSDTC instead of SqlTransaction?

My feeling is there is some sort of "obviousness" choosing msdtc over SqlTransactions that I can't figure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDTC allows you to transact across **multiple** resources, like multiple SQL Servers plus web services (over WS-Transaction) + Transactional NTFS + MSMQ + ... all in one transaction with one atomic commit.

It comes with a performance and availability cost though.

Comment: thanks. What kind of Transactional NTFS we are talking about here? WStransaction support to MSDTC is a w3c standard or some implementation from Microsoft?

Comment: It also lets you transact across multiple databases on the same server (that is two different connections, normal transactions work fine in a single connection that crosses databases).

Comment: Any resource is potentially supported because you can implement your own resource manager.; WS-Transaction is a web-services standard implemented by Microsoft among others.; Transactional NTFS is there since Vista although nobody knows about it or uses it... Basically you can have atomic file system writes.